# java completablefuture.allOff with dependent arguments

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

Is this code valid usage of `CompletableFuture.allOf(...)`

```
CompletableFuture<String> f1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "f1");
CompletableFuture<String> f2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "f2");
CompletableFuture<String> f3 = f1.thenCombineAsync(f2, (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2);
CompletableFuture<Void> all = CompletableFuture.allOf(f1, f2, f3);
all.join();
```

in javadoc:

> Among the applications of this method is to await completion of a set
>   of independent CompletableFutures before continuing a program, as in:
>   `CompletableFuture.allOf(c1, c2, c3).join();`.

But what about dependent argurments as in my example? And if it's not valid exmaple what can go wrong and why ?

---

update: maybe this helps someone, the story ended with bug in jdk-8 in completable future https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8200347#

Comment: you can think of `allOf` is just blocked until all of the passed `CompletableFuture`s are done.

Comment: @holi-java so, you are saying its valid usage ? I'm asking this since i have more complicated example when sometimes join is blocked on allOf forever, while all completable futures passed into allOf are in completed state. so I'm trying to undestand if my usages of allOf are allowed and it's not direct answer in jdk docs

Comment: If you have an issue with `allOf()`, you should post a [mcve] that reproduces it. Otherwise the "yes it is valid" answer will not help you.

Comment: You are not quite right, since I’m not sure is it  ‘issue with allOf’ or misuse ... docs are not clear for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction on the `CompletableFutures` that you pass to `allOf()`, but it is your responsibility to make sure that they all eventually complete.

This implies for example that you `complete()` the ones that you have instantiated with `new`.